# Determine whether the series converges or diverges?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, convergence-divergence

For the series $$\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}\dfrac{3n^2+8n}{7n^3-4n^2+11},$$ I was thinking of using the limit comparison test to $\dfrac{1}{n}$ but is there a better way?

Comment: From $n$ equals what? Also, you should really know how to use latex by now.

Comment: Using the limit comparison test is OK. Is obvious that the limit is finite and not 0

Answer (score 2):

$$\dfrac{1}{3n}\lt\dfrac{3n^2+8n}{7n^3-4n^2+11}\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\forall n\in\mathbb{N}.$$